# Switching to a new activity as a rewarded ad reward

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, rewardedvideoad

I am trying to set the function to switch to a new activity when watching a rewarded ad. The function is realized through the use of a picture. My code works like this. When he clicks on the picture, he shows an ad with a reward, and if the user has not watched the ad and closed the ad, he will still get to the new activity if he did not watch the ad. What's wrong with my code?)

```
      
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_selection);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "SAonCreate");

    MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) { }
    });
    mRewardedVideoAd= MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);

    mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917",new AdRequest.Builder().build());      // You need to pass your rewared video ad Id here...

    mRewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(new RewardedVideoAdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
            mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917",new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            onRewardedVideoAdClosed();

        }

        @Override
        public void onRewarded(RewardItem rewardItem) {
            adHasBeenSeen = 1;
            Toast.makeText(SelectionActivity.this, R.string.congratulations, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {
            //User clicked on ad here write your caching code here....
            Toast.makeText(SelectionActivity.this, "Clicked on Ad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int i) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRewardedVideoCompleted() {


        }
    });


    findViewById(R.id.rad_button6).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
                Intent intent = new Intent(SelectionActivity.this, TutorialActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("i", Integer.parseInt(imageView.getTag().toString()));
                startActivity(intent);
                mRewardedVideoAd.show();
                findViewById(R.id.rad_button6).setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(SelectionActivity.this, R.string.please_wait, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    findViewById(R.id.rad_button10).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
                Intent intent = new Intent(SelectionActivity.this, TutorialActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("i", Integer.parseInt(imageView.getTag().toString()));
                startActivity(intent);
                mRewardedVideoAd.show();
                findViewById(R.id.rad_button10).setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(SelectionActivity.this, R.string.please_wait, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: `onRewardedVideoCompleted` doesn't have any code in it.  How are you supposed to know that the video was watched?

Comment: use intent in `onRewardedVideoCompleted`

Answer (score 0):

The answer is - put booalen at the code.

```
boolean rewardedwatch;


  public void showVideoAds(final View view) {
       if (mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
           mRewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(new RewardedVideoAdListener() {
               @Override
               public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {

               }

               @Override
               public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {

               }

               @Override
               public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {

               }

               @Override
               public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
                   mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-6197761637111122/1983080566",new AdRequest.Builder().build());
                   if (rewardedwatch) {
                       Toast.makeText(SelectionActivity.this, R.string.congratulations, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view;
                       Intent intent = new Intent(SelectionActivity.this, TutorialActivity.class);
                       intent.putExtra("i", Integer.parseInt(imageView.getTag().toString()));
                       startActivity(intent);
                       imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                       rewardedwatch = false;
                   }

               }


               @Override
               public void onRewarded(RewardItem rewardItem) {
                   rewardedwatch = true;



               }


               @Override
               public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {
                   //User clicked on ad here write your caching code here....
                   Toast.makeText(SelectionActivity.this, "Clicked on Ad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

               }

               @Override
               public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int i) {

               }

               @Override
               public void onRewardedVideoCompleted() {
                   rewardedwatch = true;

               }
           });

           mRewardedVideoAd.show();
       }
       else {
           Toast.makeText(SelectionActivity.this, R.string.please_wait, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
   }
```